# python secrets security evaluation

Tags: random-number-generator

The python library [secrets](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/secrets.html#module-secrets) gives a title as;

> "Secrets - Generate secure random numbers for managing secrets"

and makes a distinction from "random module" by

> In particularly, secrets should be used in preference to the default
>   pseudo-random number generator in the random module, which is designed
>   for modelling and simulation, not security or cryptography.

What are the methods the secret use?

And, are there any security evaluation of python's secret library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you RTFM?  It's right in the link you provided above: "The secrets module provides access to the most secure source of randomness that your operating system provides."

If you trace is back it uses [os.urandom](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.urandom)() which "... returns random bytes from an OS-specific randomness source. The returned data should be unpredictable enough for cryptographic applications, though its exact quality depends on the OS implementation. On a UNIX-like system this will query /dev/urandom, and on Windows it will use CryptGenRandom()."